# Spring validation of request object error can't find message in @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

All other errors are working fine through ControllerAdvice except the ones throw from validator behind the scenes, the controller advice catches the exception but can not find messages form @autowired message source. Is this because of the way the validator invokes errorhandling? Running as a Spring Boot App in eclipse. Spring Boot version 1.2.1.RELEASE. Also using spring cloud config.

```
  @RestController
public class AutoController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutoController.class);

    @Autowired
    private AutoFacade autoFacade;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/policies/policy/{policyNbr}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public AutoPolicy getPolicyDetails(@Valid GetPolicyDetails reqModelObj) {   

        AutoPolicy policyDetails = autoFacade.getPolicyDetails(reqModelObj.getPolicyNbr());

        return policyDetails;
    }
}
```

ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionProcessor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestExceptionProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler({APIServerErrorException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody

    public APIStatus serverError(APIServerErrorException ex) {

        int statusCd = Integer.parseInt(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString());
        String statusMessage = messageSource.getMessage("internal.error.status.msg.500", null, Locale.US);

        String errorURL = null;
        List<APIError> errorInfoList = ex.getApiErrorList();

        if (errorInfoList == null || errorInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            int errorCode = (ex.getCode() > 0 ? ex.getCode() : 500000);
            String errorType = messageSource.getMessage("internal.error.error.type.500", null, Locale.US);
            APIError apiError = new APIError(errorCode, errorType, ex.getMessage());
            errorInfoList = new ArrayList<APIError>();
            errorInfoList.add(apiError);    
        } 

        return new APIStatus(statusCd, errorURL, statusMessage, errorInfoList);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({APINotFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public APIStatus notFoundError(APINotFoundException ex) {

        int statusCd = Integer.parseInt(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
        String statusMessage = messageSource.getMessage("not.found.status.msg.404", null, Locale.US);

        String errorURL = null;
        List<APIError> errorInfoList = ex.getApiErrorList();

        if (errorInfoList == null || errorInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            int errorCode = (ex.getCode() > 0 ? ex.getCode() : 404000);
            String errorType = messageSource.getMessage("not.found.error.type.404", null, Locale.US);
            APIError apiError = new APIError(errorCode, errorType, ex.getMessage());
            errorInfoList = new ArrayList<APIError>();
            errorInfoList.add(apiError);    
        } 

        return new APIStatus(statusCd, errorURL, statusMessage, errorInfoList);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({APIClientErrorException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public APIStatus clientError(APIClientErrorException ex) {

        int statusCd = Integer.parseInt(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
        String statusMessage = messageSource.getMessage("bad.request.status.msg.400", null, Locale.US);

        String errorURL = null;
        List<APIError> errorInfoList = ex.getApiErrorList();

        if (errorInfoList == null || errorInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            int errorCode = (ex.getCode() > 0 ? ex.getCode() : 400000);
            String errorType = messageSource.getMessage("bad.request.error.type.400", null, Locale.US);
            APIError apiError = new APIError(errorCode, errorType, ex.getMessage());
            errorInfoList = new ArrayList<APIError>();
            errorInfoList.add(apiError);    
        } 

        return new APIStatus(statusCd, errorURL, statusMessage, errorInfoList);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    @ResponseBody
    public APIStatus validationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

        int statusCd = Integer.parseInt(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.toString());
        String statusMessage = messageSource.getMessage("unprocessable.entity.status.msg.422", null, Locale.US);

        String errorURL = null;
        int errorCode =  422000;
        String errorType = messageSource.getMessage("unprocessable.entity.error.type.422", null, Locale.US);
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();      
        List<com.fbitn.api.errors.FieldError> apiFieldErrors = new ArrayList<com.fbitn.api.errors.FieldError>();

        for (FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
            String errorMessage =  messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, Locale.US);
            com.fbitn.api.errors.FieldError apiFieldError = new com.fbitn.api.errors.FieldError(fieldError.getField(), errorMessage);
            apiFieldErrors.add(apiFieldError);
        }
        APIError apiError = new APIError(errorCode, errorType, "Validation Error", apiFieldErrors);
        List<APIError> errorInfoList = new ArrayList<APIError>();
        errorInfoList.add(apiError);    

        return new APIStatus(statusCd, errorURL, statusMessage, errorInfoList);
    }   

    @ExceptionHandler({Throwable.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public APIStatus unhandledError(Throwable ex) {



        int statusCd = Integer.parseInt(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString());
        String statusMessage = messageSource.getMessage("test", null, Locale.US);

        String errorURL = null;
        int errorCode = 500000;
        String errorType = messageSource.getMessage("internal.error.error.type.500", null, Locale.US);
        APIError apiError = new APIError(errorCode, errorType, ex.getMessage());
        List<APIError> errorInfoList = new ArrayList<APIError>();
        errorInfoList.add(apiError);     

        logger.error("Unhandled Error", ex);
        return new APIStatus(statusCd, errorURL, statusMessage, errorInfoList);
    }
}
```

Validation class

```
public class GetPolicyDetails {


    @NotNull
    @Size(min=7, max=10)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$")
    private String policyNbr;

    public String getPolicyNbr() {
        return policyNbr;
    }

    public void setPolicyNbr(String policyNbr) {
        this.policyNbr = policyNbr;
    }
}
```

Application yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: auto
  messages:
    basename: messages
    encoding: UTF-8
    cacheSeconds: -1  
endpoints:
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
default: 
  locale:en_US
```

Project structure

```
  src/main/resources
       messages_en.properties
```

Properties.

```
internal.error.status.msg.500=Internal Error
test=test
internal.error.errror.type.500=Internal Error

bad.request.status.msg.400 = Bad Request
bad.request.error.type.400 = Bad Request

not.found.status.msg.404 = Not Found
not.found.error.type.404 = Not Found

unprocessable.entity.status.msg.422 = Unprocessable Entity
unprocessable.entity.error.type.422 = Unprocessable Entity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MessageSource.class) was being used in bootstrap process, but with cloud config, this resource was never loaded, the default MessageSource was used without my messages. Two ways to fix it

Add this to Application class to overwrite the default.

```
 @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames( "classpath:messages" );
    // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
    // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage( true );
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds( 0 );

    return messageSource;
    }
```

Or add a factory to order the load preference in meta-inf..

```
# Bootstrap components
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
```